# Spark SQL cassandra delete records

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to delete some records based on a select query?

I have this query,

`Select min(id) from ID having count(*)>1` which will show the duplicates. I need to get those ids and delete them. How can I do it in spark sql?

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL does not support DELETE.

If the number of ids to delete is small, you can do it using the Cassandra driver instead of through Spark:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import com.datastax.driver.core.{Cluster, Session, BatchStatement}
import com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder

val cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(host_ip).build()
val session = cluster.connect(keyspace)

val idsToDelete = ... // perform your query and collect the ids

val queries = idsToDelete.map({ id => QueryBuilder.delete().from(keyspace, table).where(QueryBuilder.eq("id", id)) })
val batch = batchStatement().addAll(queries.asJava)
session.execute(batch)

cluster.close
```